# Notepad++ Insert a character before the last three characters in every line

Tags: notepad++

Is it possible and how do I insert a character before the last three characters in every line?

For example, I have something like this:

```
5.400
830
400
1.740
1.000
2.600
310
2.280
830
520
4.650
1.450
930
5.000
```

And I need it like this:

```
5.#400
#830
#400
1.#740
1.#000
2.#600
#310
2.#280
#830
#520
4.#650
1.#450
#930
5.#000
```

Comment: what should be the result for `12.34`?

Comment: @Toto I don't have 12.34 It's either 1.234 or 123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?=...$)`
- Replace with: `#`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?=     # positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
    ...     # 3 any character but newline
    $       # end of line
)       # end lookahead
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]